# Install / adding libserial to eclipse C++ ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, libserial

I haven't used C++ in a while but I was able to setup eclipse and setup the basics. I need to write a program using libserial to communicate with a MC and I'm clueless on how to add the libserial library. I was able to download it from the official website (http://libserial.sourceforge.net/) but cant figure out how to install it.

Can anybody put up a quick Tutorial on how adding libserial to an eclipse project. Until now my includes give me an unresolved inculsion error at these lines:

```
#include <SerialStream.h>
using namespace LibSerial;
```

thanks.

PS: I'm new to programming on ubuntu